# log4j is not logging to file

Tags: java, log4j, tomcat7

I am developing my site on my local machine, using a test server and from test server, it is sent to real server.

All my log4j.properties files are identical.

on local machine and test server it works properly creating log files such as system_logs.log.2013-12-24-AM

However, log4j cannot log the real server in this way.

- local machine path: D:\jplatform2\tomcat7
- test server path: C:\Program Files\Tomcat7
- real server path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0 
  (it wasnt me installing the real server ......)

can it be caused by the path, i.e. due to spaces?

My development is all 64 bit and I am using tomcat 7

Thanks in advance

log4j.properties file:

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file                            = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern                = '.'yyyy-MM-dd-a
log4j.appender.file.File                       = ${catalina.base}/logs/system_logs.log
log4j.appender.file.layout                     = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern   = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout                          = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target                   = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout                   = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger                               = DEBUG, file, stdout
```

Also, i dont know if related but there is a constant error in my tomcat error log files like tomcat7-stderr.2013-12-25.log

```
Handler error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad level "DEBUG"
    at java.util.logging.Level.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.configure(FileHandler.java:314)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:99)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:536)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:479)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's Tomcat 7 on both production and deployment?  There's  a similar bug in Tomcat 6 https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44298

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the logger set in a static context. I was experiencing a similar issue, I had a static logger initialized in the class and being later used in a static method and was experiencing this issue. After that I followed this [Apache Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/commons/Logging/StaticLog) and fix it doing this:

```
  public static void doStuff(...) {
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog("stuff");
    log.warn(...);
  }
```

Comment: The stack trace in the question doesn't have developer's specific code invocations. It's invoked directly by catalina on startup.